# C implemented shell - Stops after piped commands

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am currently working on writing a shell program in C. In the current version my program can execute single commands and only 2 piped commands (e.g. cat [file name] | less), but after executing the piped commands the program exits and I am back at the default linux shell.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
char *commands[400];
char *split;
char *ui = NULL;

char *args1[400];
char *args2[400];

void take_commands(char *a, char *b[]){
    int i = 0;
    split = strtok(a, "\n ");
    while (split != NULL) { 
        b[i++] = split;
        split = strtok(NULL, "\n ");    
        //printf("%s \n", split);
    }
    b[i] = NULL;
}

void exec_commands(){
//  printf("%s\n", commands[0]);
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        if(execvp(commands[0], commands) == -1){
            perror("command not found");
            exit(errno);
        }
    }
    else{
        int s;
        waitpid(-1, &s, 0);
    }
}

void pipe_commands(){
    int fds[2];
    pipe(fds);
    int i;
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        close(fds[1]);
        dup2(fds[0], 0);
        if(execvp(args2[0], args2) == -1){
            perror("command not found");
            exit(errno);
        }
    }else{
        close(fds[0]);
        dup2(fds[1], 1);
        if(execvp(args1[0], args1) == -1){
            perror("command not found");
            exit(errno);
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    while(1){
        shell_msg();
        getline(&ui, &capacity, stdin);
        if(strchr(ui, '|') != NULL){
            // piped commands are executed here
            printf("piped command\n");
            char split1[100];
            char split2[100];
            char *p;
            p = strtok(ui, "|");
            strcpy(split1, p);
            //printf("%s\n", split1);;
            p = strtok(NULL, "\n");
            strcpy(split2, p);
            //printf("%s\n", split2);
            take_commands(split1, args1);
            //printf("%s %s \n", args1[0], args2[0]);
            take_commands(split2, args2);
            pipe_commands();
            continue;
        }
        if(strcmp(ui,"\n")==0){
            perror("Please type in a command " );
            continue;
        }       
        take_commands(ui, commands);
        if (strcmp(commands[0], "q") == 0) {
            printf("SYSTEM : Shell is exiting\n");
            return 0;
        }
        exec_commands(); // Call execvp() for single commands
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO ! just an advice : please avoid global variables in your code it's not recommended for reliability !

Comment: I'm pretty sure `dup2()` is the culprit.

Comment: How exactly should I change it?